# How can I get Rubymine to show an accurate progress bar for Cucumber tests?

Tags: cucumber, rubymine

Using Rubymine to run all the Cucumber tests in a folder, the progress bar has no total number of tests, so it just sits at halfway done all the way through. Rspec tests show the total number and the progress bar works fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible. RSpec does count examples before running them reporting actual examples count (see [BaseFormatter.start](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter.rb#L42)). Cucumber reports tests as they run, without counting, fully relying on gherkin parser. So it's almost impossible to count them before they're all executed.